# Get information from 2 tables using PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm wondering if you could help me with a question regarding PHP & MySQL. I'm trying to get information from 2 tables in 1 overall query for a website inbox. Meaning that from the messages table I want to find: Sender, Recipient, Message, Time, etc

And from the second table I want to find the senders actual Name, Memeber Type, Age, and maybe a few other pieces of data.

Could anybody help me to sort out this problem.  I have read that maybe I need to use Join or Join Left to connect the tables but cant' work out exactly how it could work for my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `OtherTable` contains a `UserId` field with a value equal to that of `Sender` from `MessagesTable`:

```
SELECT Sender, Recipient, ..., Name, MemberType, ... FROM MessagesTable
LEFT JOIN OtherTable ON OtherTable.UserId = MessagesTable.Sender
```

Comment: Thank you very much - That answer with an example has been very helpful.One or 2 questions though - Is the * statement still valid in this case or do you have to type out every column, i.e. SELECT *, Name, MemberType, ... FROM MessagesTable.. And does WHERE still work if added to the end?

Comment: @user2184018, sure, `*` and `WHERE` can still be used.

Comment: @user2184018, do note though that if a column from `MessagesTable` has the same name with a column from `OtherTable`, then most drivers will only return the last column's value by default. In this case you should consider aliasing the column names using `AS`.

Comment: I don't think any of the columns do in this case but thanks for the information, it's very useful to know and I'm sure it will come in very handy so I'll have a look into it - Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You need a join of some sort, for example:

```
SELECT messages.sender, messages.recipient, users.name FROM messages JOIN users ON users.id = messages.user_id
```

Check out this [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins), definitely worthy of a bookmark.